# Delphi FMX, How to validate inputs in TStringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is there a way to validate inputs in Delphi FMX TStringGrid?

For example:

- if u need the cell to accept only numbers.
- if u need the cell accept special format text.
- if u want to prevent the cell from using specific chars.

Comment: what if you do the validation before insert the data?

Comment: Please, only tag your question with the general `delphi` tag and one specific version tag if needed. And **never** tag with irrelevant tags! Fmx did not exist yet when `Delphi XE` was released! Please edit your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `*special format*`? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: special format like coordinates for example 40° 26.767′ N 79° 58.933′ W or 40.446° N 79.982° W

Comment: @William, I cant intercept keys pressed on the grid to validate inputs before insertion or maybe its hard to me to figure it out.

Comment: Use the `OnEditingDone` event and write a handler that does the necessary validations.